# ReactDOM Style element empty on createElement

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For some reason when trying to createElement with defined style, it results in style not being applied.

```
    const breakpointStyle = {
      height: 123,
      display: 'block',
      width: '100%',
      clear: 'both',
    };

    const breakpointElement = document.createElement(
      'div',
      { style: { breakpointStyle } },
      ' '
    );
```

This results in an empty div with no style.

```
<div> </div>
```

I'm using insertBefore to insert it and the div appears in the source. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how styles work when using `document.createElement`. Why are you using `createElement` at all?

Comment: Additionally, `style: { breakpointStyle }` creates an object with a key `breakpointStyle`. You just want `style: breakpointStyle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the second argument of createElement should not be mixed up with option, as properties of the element, and with ElementCreationOptions. If I understand your question correctly, that is what happened here.

The second argument expects a string value, identifying an element instance. This allows you to, for example, create custom elements by customise built-in ones.

In your case, you could write:

```
class MyCustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.style.height = '123px';
    this.style.display = 'block';
    this.style.width = '100%';
    this.style.clear = 'both';
  }
}
customElements.define('my-custom-div', MyCustomDiv, { extends: 'div' });
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div', 'my-custom-div');
document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv)
```

Output:

```
<div is="my-custom-div" style="height: 123px; display: block; width: 100%; clear: both;"></div>;
```

Or, a more common way to set properties:

```
 const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');
 myCustomDiv.style.height = '123px';
 ... and so on.
```

Here is an good article about custumize built-in elements: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

But in the article the author points out a more modern way at google developers:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/

I hope this could be to any help for you.